# TCP/IP books for windows OS

Tags: c, winapi, tcp, winsock

I've heard about these TCP/IP books which apparently seem to focus on TCP/IP in UNIX

[TCP-Illustrated-Vol.1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633469)
[TCP-Illustrated-Vol.2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020163354X)

Apart from the code introduced in these books, Are there any differences between TCP/IP implementation from windows?

If yes, Can you suggest some other TCP/IP books for windows platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Network Programming for Microsoft Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735615799) is THE book. It's quite old, but that doesn't matter. It's not a simple subject, the book can be a bit dense and it's not a hand holding 'for dummies' book, but I've yet to find a better book on the subject.

Of course, you also probably want to have the two Stevens' books that you link to to hand as well as they're great for the platform independent stuff.

As for differences, well, Windows more or less implements the BSD socket API but also provides alternative APIs which are often more appropriate for the Windows platform. Things like overlapped I/O and IO Completion Ports are a much more sensible route to take on Windows if you are looking for scalability and server side coding. The BSD API is probably fine for simple servers and single threaded clients. If you need some example code for IO Completion Port based designs then I have some [here](http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html).

Answer (score 1):

I [asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1108405/135758) back in 2009. The actual TCP/IP protocol is simply that - a protocol. Under the hood, Unix and Windows implement TCP/IP in the same way; how else would they be able to talk to each other?

The difference, as Len said, is in the APIs. Windows implements the BSD API so you can do basic portable socket programming, but if you want something with higher performance, you have to delve into platform specifics, or use a third party library. I assume since you're asking this question, you want to learn this stuff for yourself.

I implemented a IO Completion Port based system, and while I can't share the exact code, I can point you towards some of the resources I learned from, such as [this codeproject page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/iocp_server_client.aspx), [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302334.aspxhttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302334.aspx), [and this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/aa365198%28VS.85%29.aspx).